# How to erase an element from my vector that has user class parameters?

Tags: c++, class, vector

So my job is to describe the functions and I'm working on the `void erase()` function that is supposed to remove the element of the vector given the string name. teacher only gave us prototypes to for a phonebook assignment. He also gave us a built `main()` and we are not allowed to change his `main()` or prototypes, only describe them.
Listed first is the prototypes, then my work, then the main.

PROTOYPES

```
    #ifndef PHONEBOOK_H
    #define PHONEBOOK_H
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    class Person
    {
    public:
        Person();
        Person(string new_name, int new_phone);
        string get_name() const;
        int get_phone() const;
        bool operator < (Person p) const;
        void print() const;

    private:
        string name;
        int phone;
    };

    void add_people(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void erase(vector<Person> &phone_book, string name);
    void sort(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void shuffle(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void reverse(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void print(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    int lookup(const vector<Person> &phone_book, string name);
    #endif
```

MY WORK

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <vector>
        #include <time.h>
        #include "phonebook.h"

        Person::Person()
        {
            name = "NONE";
            phone = 0000000;

        }
        Person::Person(string new_name, int new_phone)
        {
            name=new_name;
            phone=new_phone;
        }
        string Person::get_name() const
        {
            return name;
        }
        int Person::get_phone() const
        {
            return phone;
        }
        bool Person::operator < (Person p) const
        {
            return name < p.name;
        }
        void Person::print() const
        {
            cout << endl << name << " " << phone;
        }

        void add_people(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the new name: ";
            string s;
            getline(cin, s);
            cout << "Please enter new number: ";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            phone_book.push_back(Person(s,number));
        }
        void erase(vector<Person> &phone_book, string name)
        {   
        }
        void sort(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
        }
        void shuffle(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
        }
        void reverse(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
        }
        void print(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < phone_book.size(); i++)
                cout << phone_book[i] << " ";
        }

        int lookup(const vector<Person> &phone_book, string name)
        {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < phone_book.size() && phone_book[i].get_name() != name)
                {
                    i++;
                    return phone_book[i].get_phone();
                }
        }
```

THE MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include "phonebook.h"

using namespace std;




int main()
{

    vector<Person> phone_book;
    string name;
    int number;
    int answer;

    srand((int)(time(0)));

    phone_book.push_back(Person("Bruin, Joe", 5556456));
    phone_book.push_back(Person("Simpson, Homer", 5557471));
    phone_book.push_back(Person("Duffman, Barry", 5533331));


    cout <<"\n";
    cout << "Your phone book contains the following names and numbers: \n";

    for (int i=0; i < phone_book.size(); i++)
    {

        phone_book[i].print();
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout <<"\n";
    answer=0;

    while (answer != 8)
    {
        cout << "\nChoose from the following options:\n\n";

        cout << "1) Add people to the phone book.\n";
        cout << "2) Erase a person from the phone book.\n";
        cout << "3) Sort the phone book.\n";
        cout << "4) Shuffle the phone book.\n";
        cout << "5) Reverse the phone book.\n";
        cout << "6) Print the phone book.\n";
        cout << "7) Look up a person in the phone book.\n";
        cout << "8) Quit.\n\n";

        cin >> answer;

        string clear;

        getline(cin, clear);

        if (answer == 1)
            add_people(phone_book);
        else if (answer == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter a name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            erase(phone_book, name);

        }
        else if (answer == 3)
            sort(phone_book);
        else if (answer == 4)
            shuffle (phone_book);
        else if (answer == 5)
            reverse(phone_book);
        else if (answer == 6)
        {
            cout <<"\n";
            cout << "Your phone book contains the following names and numbers: \n";
            print(phone_book);
        }
        else if (answer ==7)
        {                   
            cout << "Enter a name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            int number = lookup(phone_book, name); 
            if (number > 0)
            {
                cout << "\n\nThe number for " << name << " is: " << number << "\n\n";
            }
            else
                cout << name << " not found in the phone book.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And if you guys could give me pointers on the sort function, its supposed to order the elements of the vector lexicographically according to their respective string paramter

Answer (score 0):

Your lookup function finds the position of the Person with the given name in the vector. You can use this index, along with the [vector erase function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) to remove the Person from the vector.

BTW, in your lookup function, you might also want to consider what happens in the case where there is no Person with the given name.